# In python, can I create a closure with an anonymous function?

Tags: python, closures, human-readable

Out of curiosity, I'd like to see if there's a better answer than what's below.
How can I convert this:

```
def counter():
    ctr = 0
    def inner():
        ctr += 1
        return ctr
    return inner
counter = counter()
```

into this javascript equivalent?

```
counter = (function() {
    let ctr = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++ctr;
    } //inner anonymous func
})(); //outer func, called and forgotten, sort of.
```

The python above is fine, I was just curious if there was a faster/more readable way to do this.

To be clear, I don't want the outer factory function to be available after its called, and I want it to be called as soon as its defined. Think of it as a closure singleton.
Thanks!

Comment: The subject of your question seems to ask for a Python solution, while the body of your question seems to ask for a JavaScript solution, and apparently you give the solution for both languages. What is the problem?

Comment: If you look for a code review for essentially working code, then this is more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The python above is fine? Did you test it? `ctr += 1` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: "The python above is fine" no, it isn't. It will throw a `UnboundLocal` error. if you actually try to use `counter()`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I gave the python solution I've been using, but wanted to know if there is a better way. The javascript example shows using anonymous functions, none of them have names. Maybe it is a code review thing, but not sure. Seemed to fit here, and I couldn't find answers to it.